# Delay part of setTimeout is ignored, Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a sleep/delay function to make an animation that the div slides out. At the moment it will instantly turn -60em without any delay at all which prevent the div from slide out.

Dunno why `setTimeout` ignores the time delay.

```
for(activeSlide; activeSlide < i; activeSlide++){
    animateLeft(activeSlide);

    function animateLeft(activeSlide){
        div[activeSlide].style.left = step+'em';
        step -= 6;

        if(step < -60) {
            return; 
        }
        setTimeout(animateLeft(activeSlide), 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: When is `step` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `animateLeft(activeSlide)` immediately and setting a timeout to call *its return value* in 5 seconds.

You want this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { animateLeft(activeSlide); }, 5000);
```

Or else this:

```
setTimeout(animateLeft, 5000, activeSlide);
```